# DateTimeFormatterBuilder#appendText(TemporalField, Map<Long,String>) throws exception when parsing

Tags: java, java-time, date-parsing, localdate

I'm trying to parse text that represents a `LocalDate` value with the `IsoField.QUARTER_OF_YEAR` using a `DateTimeFormatter` returned by the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder#buildFormatter()` method.

The problematic text is  "20 Oct 2018 Q2". The quarter value ("Q2") is admittedly incorrect for a conventional calendar year, here "2018". However, I am working with a fiscal year which ends on June 30, so that the date "20 Oct 2018" would be in the fiscal year's second quarter.

The formatter is built with the following code:

```
TemporalQuery<LocalDate> query = LocalDate::from;
String pattern = “d MMM uuuu qqq”;
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US");
TemporalField tf = IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR;
Map<Long, String> m = new Hashtable<>();
m.put(4L, “Q2”);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()                                                                                
                                       .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                       .appendPattern(pattern)
                                       .appendText(tf, m)
                                       .toFormatter(locale);
TemporalAccessor value = formatter.parse(text, query)
```

Attempts to parse generate a `DateTimeParseException` with the error message:
“Text '20 Oct 2018 Q2' could not be parsed at index 0”

I’ve tried changing the order in which the `parseCaseInsensitive()` … `appendText()` methods are called. The exception is still thrown, although the specified index is 14 in one of the variations.

Possible reason for problem:
The DateTimeFormatterBuilder#appendText(TemporalField, Map) method may work only in format operations, and not for parsing as here.

Thanks in advance for any ideas or help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to parse the quarter year part twice - once per pattern instruction (using letter q) and once per builder-instruction (using method appendText). Solution: Remove the qqq-part in your pattern and **use "d MMM uuuu "**.

Some remarks however:

- Fiscal years are not supported at all.
- Use better `HashMap` instead of outdated `Hashtable`.
- The example code has special quotation marks instead of standard char (").
- The parsed value is equivalent to `LocalDate.of(2018, 10, 20)` (and has no information about your special quarters).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did a bit more research after asking the question and learned my original approach was way off the mark :). About your remarks:
- Indeed fiscal years are not supported, which is why I'm doing something on my own. I already have a solution, but it's not as elegant as the <TemporalField, Map> feature, which I could use if the QUARTER value was located in the same position relative to the rest of the temporal values (most often at the end), but I want to maintain maximum flexibility.
- HashMap noted
- 'Parsed value' issue no longer important.